# How can I type hint a class, rather than an instance of the class?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5

How can I type hint a class, rather than an instance of the class?

I tried this, but I get `Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.`

```
class Foo {
}

class Bar extends Foo {
}

class Baz extends Foo {
}

function test(c: Foo) {
    new c();
}

test(Baz);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `typeof`:

```
class Foo {
}

class Bar extends Foo {
}

class Baz extends Foo {
}

function test(c: typeof Foo) {
    new c();
}

test(Baz);
```